# build form in joomla and dispaly the list of content

Tags: php, html, forms, joomla, formbuilder

I want build a form in joomla 3.3.1 and display content of form in list with several pages such as link below:
http://alkafeel.net/persian/zyara/view.php?pageNum_Recordset1=3122&totalRows_Recordset1=158555

but I have problem because

1. I don't find good form builder for joomla 3.3.1
2. i don't know whats the html code for display list of content that  user submit
3. How can put the search box for search between displayed content 
   and also I should say I install rsform pro extension v1.49.7 but don't work correctly infact no one of options work

Answer (score 0):

We are using [Chronoforms](http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoforms.html) for our forms. A great component with lot's of plugins and features. You are also able to access the formdata before submit. You can add custom code (html/php/js) to your forms and it's extremly flexible.

Just give it a try ;)

BTW: rsform should also work, it's a great component too! Maybe there is something wrong with your include of the plugin files or with your template.
All components add some scripts to the header with the given Joomla-function. Maybe there is something wrong with your configuration.